# How to test random numbers within the range with the dieharder test suite

Tags: php, testing, random

I'd like to test my randomness algorithm, base on some seeds and hashes. The main point, that my algo gives only interger numbers in range (from 2 to 12)/ And i'll d like to be sure that output will be really random.
How can i test this with dieharder test suite? Is it possible to provide some range for example?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to transform your RNG to something diaharder expects. That seems to be a 32-bit integer. There is no other way to run this suite with a different RNG-model. The transformation of your RNG to something which produces 32-bit integers might be not that simple (regarding bias and co.). Why do you need this kind of test? You are not trying to use a custom-build RNG, are you?

Comment: hm... i'm actually generating 32-bit integers, i suppose.

I use /dev/urandom based RNG, but add my own algorithm over it laster. So i need to be sure that my algorithm  does not provide "invalid" random

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are a lot of very good RNGs to use. Why build one for yourself? There should be also many good RNGs ready to use reseeding or ther approaches to incorporate additional entropy from urandom.

Comment: The goal is to make provably fair system for my users. So i could not just tell them: 'well, guys, i use random_int() method, i swear' =)
that's why i should make all that stuff with seeds and hashes

Comment: But doesn't provably fair mean, that you already proved randomness (when fair = uniformity)? If you provide more information, maybe there is a better solution. Online casinos also stick to common algorithms i bet (cryptographic rngs with external entropy). I also think they are very hardly pushed by goverment rules to give analysis about their "fairness".

Comment: I think I read somewhere that [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) could be configured for specific ranges, but I'm not sure and I've never found the time to dig into the tool in any detail.